# Python 2 tuple / list unpacking using star throws SyntaxError

Tags: python-2.7, iterable-unpacking

Why does the following code throw a `SyntaxError` for `*phones` in Python 2.7.3?

```
contact = ('name', 'email', 'phone1', 'phone2')
name, email, *phones = contact
```

Was this introduced in Python 3 and not backported? How can I get this to work in Python 2? That is, if there isn't some trivial way to fix things here.

Comment: Yes, it's Python 3 only and not back ported

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-3132/ - this was specified here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup, the extended unpacking syntax (using `*` to take the rest) is Python 3.x only. The closest you can get in Python 2.x is explicitly slicing the parts you want from the remainder:

```
contact = ('name', 'email', 'phone1', 'phone2')
(name, email), phones = contact[:2], contact[2:]
```

If you needed it to work on arbitrary iterables, then you can use something like:

```
from itertools import islice
i = iter(contact)
(name, email), phone = tuple(islice(i, 2)), list(i)
```